# Qt: the proper way to draw a widget over a parent widget efficiently

Tags: c++, qt, widget

I have a parent widget P which is a graphic-scene widget that is drawing some picture(QImage) of large size, so its paint function is expensive to be called.

Now I would like to add a small widget C which updating on its own of 10Hz and I would like it to have the graphic-scene widget as its parent.

C does appeared on the left top corner of the P widget as expected.
However I found the 10Hz updating of C also trigger a 10Hz updating of the P and used a lot of CPU.

How could I prevent this? C does not need to be transparent any way.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot prevent the child update of at a frequency of 10Hz to trigger the parent update at a frequency of 10Hz. What you can do is make rendering as efficient as it could be.

Thus you have to use pixmaps for drawing P. Each time you draw the QImage in the paint event you get the penalty from using QImage. Your paintevent should be

```
void QWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
{
  if(somethingHasChanged())
     updatePixmap();
  drawSavedPixmap();
}
```

This still holds even if you have a saved QImage.